# Tomacat service stopped with two deployed applications

Tags: windows, apache, tomcat, tomcat7

I have two applications running under the same server with the same port:
http://localhost:8080/app1
http://localhost:8080/app2
I installed Tomcat7 as a windows service, when I try to running it, Tomcat hangs and stops by it self with an error message in Windows events "**The Apache Tomcat 7.0 Tomcat7 service terminated with service-specific error Incorrect function**"
When I removed one of these two applications from webapps folder( App1 or App2), Tomcat service runs smoothly without a problem.

Another condition, when I start tomcat with **cmd** (*the two applications are in the webapps folder*) the web server runs without a problem too.

I need Tomcat to start automatically with Windows services.

The question is why Tomcat service stops running with two deployed applications?
Why does it accept only one application?

PS: I tried to modify the **tomcat7w.exe** (the min and max memory) and changing the jdk version. Nothing works.

Thanks for your help.

Comment: What does your Tomcat write to `log/catalina.log` when the problem occurs?

Comment: Nothing mate. No sign for an error, just "info". I can't past all logs in comment

Comment: it stops at " PM org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig deployDirectory "

Answer (score 1):

Problem solved ^_^ Just increasing the " **PermGen space** " in **tomcat7w.exe** **-XX:MaxPermSize=2048m**

[image]